# Hamburger Icon and Title are not aligned properly

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently trying to add an hamburger icon to the toolbar but it seems that the title and the icon are not aligned properly, the icon is a little bit above the center where the title resides.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app1:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
            app1:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

This is my toolbar, I have tried to apply a style that I saw online on some blog in order to fix it and that's how it looks like (without it its even worse)

```
<style name="Custom.Widget.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
<item name="maxButtonHeight">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>

    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">72dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetStart">50dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add hamburger icon by :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Add the title by:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/toolbarTitleId"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:textSize="20sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

You can set position of title in `ToolBar` via `android:gravity="prefer position"`.